# Getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while running two independent threads

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, javafx-2

I have two classes `ResultsReader` and `ResultsReadertwo`. Both the classes extends Task class and I am using two separate threads as follows:

In class ResultsReader:

```
public void act_StartProcessing() 
    { new Thread(this).start(); }

    public void act_StopProcessing() 
    { this.cancel();}
```

In class ResultsReadertwo:

```
public void act_StartProcessing2() 
    { new Thread(this).start(); }

    public void act_StopProcessing2() 
    { this.cancel();}
```

The Exception I ma getting is as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1456)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6867)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3369)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3209)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3164)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1582)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2267)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:530)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:924)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1451)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at ebmextractor.ExtractorMonitor.set_QRS2(ExtractorMonitor.java:119)
    at ebmextractor.EBMExtractorFXMLController.act_Start(EBMExtractorFXMLController.java:428)
    ... 55 more
```

Here is a piece of code in EBMExtractorFXMLController class where I am getting error:

```
RunningQRState = false;

ExtractorMonitor QRM = new ExtractorMonitor();

QRM.set_but_Start(but_Start);
QRM.set_QRS(QueueReaderExecutorService);
QRM.set_QRS2(QueueReaderExecutorService2);    // Getting error here
QRM.act_StartProcessing();  
QRM.act_StartProcessing2();
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/pSHig4) is my `ExtractorMonitor` class where I have defined `act_StartProcessing(); and 
                 act_StartProcessing2();`

Please let me know what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem seems to be:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
at ebmextractor.ExtractorMonitor.set_QRS2(ExtractorMonitor.java:119)
```

This has nothing to do with multithreading.

The most likely reason is that this method throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`. Are you sure that you/your IDE didn't create method stubs for you that throw this exception?

The source code link you posted doesn't seem to point to the version of the class you refer to in your question. There is no line `ExtractorMonitor.java:119`.